# What are some good online Bitcoin wallets based on client-side security?

Tags: e-wallet

I just found [Bitventory](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/lxpr0/bitventory_a_simple_secure_auditable_ewallet/), which seems to be an online wallet service that requires a minimal amount of trust (it's the major design goal, at least).

Are there other services with similar goals or functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is such a service which provides exactly what your looking for it is called [StrongCoin](https://www.strongcoin.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Bccapi (http://code.google.com/p/bccapi/) solves the same problem as  Bitinventory and in a surprisingly similar way. Two android clients are in the making on top if the Bccapi, however so far only one fully functional console UI exists.

Answer (score 0):

True client side security requires 2 party signed transactions which aren't currently implemented in the maineline client/protocol.

With a two party wallet both parties (the online wallet service provider and the owner) would need to sign the transaction with their independent private key in order for it to be accepted by the network.  The wallet provider never has access to user's private key and thus can never transfers users funds.

Any solutions that exist now are stopgap at best.

Comment: What flaw do you find in the approach implemented by Bitventory?

Comment: This way if the service provider goes out of business my coins are lost forever. Bccapi, StrongCoin & Bitinventory is the way to go.

Comment: @ripper234 I took a closer look and I think Bitventory could be a secure solution.  Most "secure" online wallets use javascript to convert passphrase into determistic private key.  The problem with that is DNS spoofing or javascript injection attack means you are giving your passphrase to an attacker.  Bitinventory uses strongly signed Java applet which could reduce the risk of code replacement.

Answer (score 0):

[BitcoinSpinner](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.miracleas.bitcoin_spinner) for Android phones is an amazingly simple yet secure Bitcoin wallet. It is built on top of the [BCCAPI](http://code.google.com/p/bccapi/).

[BitcoinSpinner announcement at bitcointalk.org](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=52674.0)

Answer (score -2):

[Lumi Wallet](https://lumiwallet.com/) is a client-side HD secure wallet for BTC, ETH and a load of ERC20 token. 
it also has 2FA (strangely, many decent wallets doesn't have this)